# Error implementando Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Tengo el proyecto en el servidor de producción, y estoy pasando ciertos scripts de un proyecto local al del servidor. Y me da un error que no logro aislar.

```
ImportError at /
No module named viewsets
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://sub.domain.com/
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named viewsets
Exception Location: /home/django/django_project/django_project/urls.py in <module>, line 7
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/django/django_project',
 '/home/django',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:    Mié, 11 May 2016 13:12:07 +0200
```

Tengo los ViewSet's importados y no entiendo. Ya que en el otro proyecto la API me funcionaba perfectamente.

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

# API Imports
from .viewsets import BrandViewSet


admin.autodiscover()


# Routers API
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'brand', BrandViewSet)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
    # API Rest Framework
    url(r'^API', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Estructura del proyecto:

```
/home/django/

|--django_project/
   |--django_project/ 
   |  |--settings.py
   |  |--urls.py
   |  |--wsgi.py
   |--my_app/
   |  |--admin.py
   |  |--models.py
   |  |--serializers.py
   |  |--tests.py
   |  |--views.py
   |  |--viewsets.py
   |--manage.py
```

Comment: ¿Cómo está la estructura de tu app?, ¿estás seguro de tener el archivo `viewsets.py` dentro de tu app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que tu `urls.py` se encuentra fuera de `my_app`, la importación relativa no funciona, intenta haciendo esto:

```
# API Imports
from my_app.viewsets import BrandViewSet
```

Recuerda que la importación relativa funciona solo dentro del mismo módulo en el que te encuentras.

Para más información sobre el tema de las importaciones puedes visitar el siguiente enlace:

- [PEP 328 -- Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

Answer (score 0):

Veamos: el error dice que *"no encuentra el módulo `viewsets` en la línea 7"*, que es ésta:

```
from .viewsets import BrandViewSet
```

Tienes un `.` delante de `viewsets`, que indica un import relativo. No creo que este módulo se encuentre en el mismo directorio que `urls.py`, así que quita el punto a ver si va.

Comment: He quitado el punto y sigue saliendo exactamente el mismo error.. se ve que hay algo más. @ChemaCortes